# Mozilla Thunderbird truncates my message on reply/forward

Tags: email, thunderbird

This seems to happen randomly.  I changed it to top reply and place signature immediately below my reply.  Any ideas on why it truncates my response and forward messages? And it does not seem to do it consistently.

Thunderbird 3.1.9 is running on Windows 7 (x64).  This same behavior is exhibited on 3 different computers.

Answer (score 6):

Google shows this question asked hundreds of times.  There are many work-arounds and bug reports on this.

However it isn't a bug.  It's a feature.  The feature is intended to truncate unwanted signatures from Usenet (forum) posts.  The signature is signified by a double hyphen and a space on a line by itself "-- ".

You can turn this feature off in Thunderbird's configuration by:

> Advance -> Config Editor -> [I'll be careful] -> (search for)
>   mail.strip_sig_on_reply -> [toggle it to false].

By the way, I spend about an hour searching for how to do this on every Thunderbird install.  Hopefully this definitive answer will save Thunderbird users time.

Comment: This didn't work.  Still randomly truncates quoted emails, after the header v52.9.1

Comment: This fixed it for me! It's worth mentioning that in current Thunderbird version (102)  the Config Editor button lives in a differente place: Edit -> Settings -> General -> Config Editor

Comment: This is still a thing in 2023 (usenet really?). As Pedro mentions, go to settings, general, and config editor is at the bottom. Some users, on some of their devices, use a double dash followed by a space on its own line, before their signature. Unfortunately that causes email chains to occasionally, mysteriously, disappear.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the gmail-like "quote only what is selected" feature, not a problem. Be sure to **not** have anything selected before replying, if you want to quote everything.

Another option is that there is the text "--" somewhere in the message, which could be interpreted as "beginning of a signature": by default, Thunderbird do not quote anything **after** that. So the workaround in this case is to "select all" and the reply. In this case Thunderbird will use the feature described in the previous paragraph and quote everything, even if happens after a signature.

Answer (score 1):

From [Reply message truncated Thunderbird 3.0](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=1693655) :

> [Backup your Thunderbird Profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_backup)
>   then compact all folders.
>
> If it doesn't resolve the problem then
>   do the following :
>
> Close Thunderbird. Find and delete all
>   of the files with the .msf file
>   extension in [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Folder#Thunderbird)/Mail,
>   including your Folders (especially if
>   you are using the global inbox). You
>   must have  [How to show hidden files
>   and
>   folders](http://spywarewarrior.com/viewtopic.php?t=272)
>   and if you are using Windows you also
>   need to set "hide extensions for known
>   file types" off (just below View
>   Hidden). These are your mail summary
>   files and do not hold any messages
>   themselves. They will be rebuilt the
>   next time you open each folder in
>   Thunderbird. Compact all your folders
>   when you have completed this.

If this doesn't help, please let me know your Thunderbird version and operating system.

Comment: updated main post with this info

Comment: I understand that none of the above helped in any way ? See also the solution at the end of [how do i show full original message in reply](http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/how_do_i_show_full_original_message_in_reply).

Comment: @tone You're having the problem because of the default setting is to exclude the signature indicated by two hyphens and a space "`-- `".  You can change this default as indicated [here](https://superuser.com/a/958791/367972). from **`true`** to **`false`**.  This works for all versions of Thunderbird on all platforms.  You can play with workarounds that might work sometimes.  Changing this setting will work all the time consistently.

Comment: @L.D.James: Thanks for pitching in, but this post dates from 2010 and the poster probably has resolved his problem years ago (and didn't bother to indicate what worked for him).

Comment: **I'm sure you're right** about the poster.  My message is to the community so that anyone running into this thread will have a working resolution.  Reading all the answers there are a lot of maybe's of things that might work.  I was just reiterating the certainty that would never fail.  Hopefully, the Thunderbird developers will eventually put this option in the preference instead of where it's hidden.  They should also remove it from the default, since many people not familiar with mail list and only use it for email won't understand or care for the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sent copy.  Is it cut off? If not, try sending the message to iphone. If not cut off, the problem is probably the recipient using outlook - either a setting or a version I'm still investigating that.  A suggested workaround is to select your whole message (Ctrl_A) before clicking reply or forward in TB.

Cut and re-paste the whole quoted thread in the compose window seems to work also